# How to implement search within a UIPicker?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have UIPicker that I need to write search mechanism for. The data that is feeding this picker is an array of strings. When the user enters the search string (I have a UISearchBar that handles that.) I would like to find all strings containing the search term.  From the example below, it seems I need to write a predicate and then filter the array. The problem I am having right now is I don't know how to display the search results to the user. I tried assigning the result set back to the original array but that is not correct. Could someone suggest a technique for implementing searching of a UIPicker with a code example?

```
NSMutableArray* names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Andy", @"Bart", @"Bob", nil]; 
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'b'"];
NSArray* namesStartingWithB = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [project](http://lingsdesigns.com/public/articles/TestPickerSearch.zip)

Remember your predicate is case sensitive.  You used a lowercase b so it won't return any results.  My solution is basically the same thing Joe suggested.  I use two arrays. One array for the full dataset and then another array for the search result.  The datasource for the picker is the partial array then I just reload the picker when I do a search.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful example. I had to modify it slightly  because I am using an NSMutableArray. 

 NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'B'"];
 [arrayCountryChoices filterUsingPredicate: predicate];
 [pickerCountry reloadComponent:0]; 

This works fine. My only question is how can I restore the original dataset after a filter?

Comment: In my example, data is the original dataset and searchResults is the filtered dataset.  to restore the original I would do this: self.searchResults = [NSArray arrayWithArray:data];

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a super inventive solution, but how about just storing the results as a sperate array (i.e. searchResultsArr) and changing the data source to that? In the code just use the searchResultsArr unless it is nil. If it's nil use the full array.

make sure to call

```
[picker reloadAllComponents];
```

when you switch it out

Comment: I have attempted to code what you suggest and it is not working as expected. Do you have a working code example? As mentioned above " The problem I am having right now is I don't know how to display the search results to the user. I tried assigning the result set back to the original array but that is not correct. To be  clear, I tried to assign the search results array to the datasource for the UIPicker which is declared like this. NSMutableArray *arrayCountryChoices;